# How to create a CSV file based on row in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file `/tmp/some.txt` with below values

```
JOHN              YES     6          6            2345762
 SHAUN             NO     6          6            2345748
```

I want to create a csv file with below format (i.e based on rows. NOT based on columns).

```
JOHN,YES,6,6,2345762
SHAUN,NO,6,6,2345748
```

i tried below code

```
for i in `wc -l /tmp/some.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
do
awk  'NR==$i' /tmp/some.txt | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' >> /tmp/some.csv
done
```

here `wc -l /tmp/some.txt | awk '{print $1}'` will get the value as 2 (i.e 2 rows in text file).
and for each row `awk  'NR==$i' /tmp/some.txt | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}'` will print the 5 fields into `some.csv`file which is separated by comma.

when i execute each command separately it will work. but when i make it as a shell script i'm getting empty `some.csv` file.

Comment: why don't you just replace all blocks of spaces with a single comma?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' /tmp/some.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kart: Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$1=$1;} 1' OFS=,   Input_file  > output.csv
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. `awk` already process the file row by row, so you don't need to iterate with the `for` loop.

So you just need to run:

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' /tmp/some.txt >> /tmp/some.csv
```

Comment: That's true, it's a better answer. I just used the same command @Kart wrote.

Answer (score 1):

With `tr`, squeezing (`-s`), and then transliterating space/tab (`[:blank:]`):

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' <file.txt
```

With `sed`, substituting one or more space/tab with `,`:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g' file.txt
```

With `awk`, replacing one ore more space/tab with `,` using `gsub()` function:

```
awk 'gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ",", $0)' file.txt
```

**Example**

```
% cat foo.txt
JOHN              YES     6          6            2345762
SHAUN             NO     6          6            2345748


% tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' <foo.txt                     
JOHN,YES,6,6,2345762
SHAUN,NO,6,6,2345748

% sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g' foo.txt                   
JOHN,YES,6,6,2345762
SHAUN,NO,6,6,2345748

% awk 'gsub("[[:blank:]]+", ",", $0)' foo.txt
JOHN,YES,6,6,2345762
SHAUN,NO,6,6,2345748
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware that you can squeeze and replace in one shot with `tr`.